# jq : applying different functions/mappings over parts of an array

Tags: arrays, json, split, mapping, jq

The JSON input is a simple set

I wish to pick some of its elements based on their names
a1,..,an -> {"a1":v1,..."an':vn}
jq -j '[.a1,.a2,...,.an]'

And then use different functions f,g...
so as to finally obtain [f(v1),...,f(vk),g(vk+1),...,g(vn)]

Using a single function, the filter would be :
jq -j '[.a1,.a2,...,.an]|map(.|f)'

But i cannot see the syntax, if any, to apply different functions f,g,... over different ranges

Let me expose my concrete case :

At start, i have as JSON resulting from GPS location on the phone (using termux-location)

```
{
  "latitude": 66.32418638,
  "longitude": -121.77029769,
  "altitude": 465.46502685546875,
  "accuracy": 17.6742248535156,
  "vertical_accuracy": 36.48805236816406,
  "bearing": 0.0,
  "speed": 0.0,
  "elapsedMs": 55,
  "provider": "gps"
}
```

I would like extract latitude,longitude,elevation,accuracy
and process them differently : round the first 2 with 5 decimals,
and the last 2 to nearest integer, and leave one intact

When splitting :

```
jq -j '[.latitude,.longitude]|map(.*100000|round/100000)' in.json
jq -j '[.altitude,.accuracy]|map(.|round)' in.json
jq -j '.provider' in.json
```

**q1. But can one easily combine such filters into a single one ?

q2. When dealing with much larger arrays, it is possible to use different functions over index ranges (without having to name attributes) ?

q3. Or would one need to build a global map() function with different cases, returning f(.),g(.),... according to ranges ?
**
To solve q3, i tried to play with index() but my level in JQ is still too poor ...

- WRONG CODE *

```
jq -j '[.latitude,.longitude,.altitude,.accuracy]|map(if .|index<2 then .*100000|round/100000 else .|round end)'
```

Comment: One question per question please. What is your expected output? An array or the original object structure, only with transformations applied?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the functions directly while contructing the array:

```
[
  (.latitude, .longitude | .*100000 | round/100000),
  (.altitude, .accuracy | round),
  .provider
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/U6Tv6UdGLeG)

Or apply functions using ranges:

```
[.latitude, .longitude, .altitude, .accuracy, .provider]
| .[0:2] |= map(.*100000 | round/100000)
| .[2:4] |= map(round)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YWo_6a_3ZoM)

You could also wrap this in a custom filter, taking indices and the mapping function as parameters:

```
def myfun(i;j;f): .[i:j] |= map(f);

[.latitude, .longitude, .altitude, .accuracy, .provider]
| myfun(0; 2; .*100000 | round/100000)
| myfun(2; 4; round)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/yh2wmsMIyLG)

Output for the given sample input:

```json
[
  66.32419,
  -121.7703,
  465,
  18,
  "gps"
]
```